# Did Charles Babbage's Difference Engine use the sautoir carry mechanism from Pascal's calculator?

Tags: gears, mechanisms

We know that [Blaise Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal) built a [mechanical calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_calculator#Carry_mechanism) which had a carry mechanism called a sautoir.

[image]

You can see a video of it working [here](https://youtu.be/OpTAODDU1pg), and [here](https://youtu.be/-li5VWnqhmI).

We [know that](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=piNNAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) wrote a book of [log tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms).

In doing this, Babbage was inspired to create Log Tables mechanically, leading to his design of the [Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine#targetText=A%20difference%20engine%2C%20first%20created,small%20set%20of%20polynomial%20coefficients.).

My question is: **Did Charles Babbage's Difference Engine use the sautoir carry mechanism from Pascal's calculator?**

Comment: Based on your research, what would you conclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no. Longer answer is that the Babbage Difference engine has taken the *concept of a sautoir* and implemented something much more complicated.

Here we have two wheels representing values in the calculation, and the gear in the middle that adds.

[image]

Then to carry numbers up - there was an external device:

[image]

Keep in mind that a single number is represented vertically on a column, so the values and the carrying device were replicated vertically.

[image]

See also this [Counter](http://www.meccano.us/counter/index.html) built by a person who built a [Difference  Engine](http://www.meccano.us/difference_engines/rde_2/index.html) built out of [Meccano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meccano) - which implemented its own carry mechanism:
[image]

> This arm will engage between two of the double brackets on the detent assembly of the adjacent dial and cause it to advance by one unit.”

**Bibliography**

- [Babbage's Difference Engine No. 2, Part 2: The Calculation Section](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdra5Ms__9s)
- [Tim Robinson's Meccano Computing Machinery web site](http://www.meccano.us/)